# Combining several variables into one outcome score: How is it done in the machine learning community?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction, latent-variable, composite

I have got 8 cognitive (continuous) behaviour variables and would like to combine them into a composite score. I would then like to find the best predictors of this outcome (from about 50 predictors).

I was interested if there are alternatives to PCA/Factor analysis or latent variable model approaches which allow to model features which are non-linearly related to the input variables. I am aware of non-linear PCA but as a classical statistician would be interested if there are any other methods in the field of machine learning.

I would also be interested if it is possible to combine the development of a "composite score" and selecting a regression model to predict this composite score simultaneously within a cross-validation model building procedure.

I am grateful about any advice or references.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why are you not happy with PCA/FA approaches? It is not really clear to me what you mean by *"find[ing] a cross-validate model which maximizes prediction accuracy by modelling both feature variables and development of composite measure simultaneously"*; maybe you could try to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply You are right that my sentence does not make too much sense and I will try to elaborate my point:

Comment: I was interested if there are alternatives to PCA/FA which allow to model more features which are non-linearly related to the input variables. I am aware of non-linear PCA but as a classical statistican would be interested if there are any other methods in the field of machine learning

Comment: General remark: instead (or in addition) to providing clarifications in the comments, I suggest you edit your question to clarify/expand it. This puts it on the front page again and makes more people look at it again.

Comment: Good idea! I have update my original question.

Comment: Why do you need to use machine learning? To work through 50 predictors? To automate a process that will be repeated? I'm no machine learning expert, but from my perspective composite scores, indices, or constructs should be created using a very theory-driven - not data-driven - process. Unless all you are trying to do is data reduction. This is because there is often no way validate most behavioral/psychometric constructs. They are abstract constructs that someone defines with theory. Measures created and assessed for construct validity - but if you have no theory they are meaningless.

Comment: Dear Robin, thanks for your comments. I agree that such a data-driven composite score is not validated and I do nit know what it really measures and perhaps I should have used a different example for my question, where data reduction is the aim. I am mainly interested what kind of approaches the machine learning community is using to see if there is anything to learn from.

Comment: ML has a lot of latent variable models. If the direction you want to approach this is, I know there is a latent state which I can measure only indirectly through 8 variables, the answer depends very much on your assumptions about the latent variable. Is it discreet? Is it continuous? Is it a process over time? And perhaps more generally, is there value in estimating the latent state, can't you build a solid multivariate model estimating directly the 8 variables?

Comment: Thanks, means-to-meaning, this is very helpful.My latent variable would be continous and there is theoretical reasoning that there is only one latent variable but it may change over time (only a few measurements, but currently I owuld only assume one time point). However, in general I do not have the need to estimate the latent state and building a "solid multi-variate model" is preferable. May I ask you to provide a reference for both models? Many thnaks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This mentions about composite variable. http://www.r-bloggers.com/ecological-sems-and-composite-variables-what-why-and-how/. In R package lavann, you can create composite variable based on manifest variables (indicators).  Then this composite variable can be treated as a dependent variable or independent as per the question of interest.

Comment: Thanks Phil for your suggestions and the link. However, I wanted to know if there are machine learning alternatives to latent variable modelling or composite scores based on latent variable models which allow to model complex non-linear relationships.